# Does "unbremsbar" exist in German?

Tags: word-usage

It seems so it doesn't exist in any dictionary, but... I find some sentences of it on [reverso](https://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/unbremsbar) where it seems to mean unbreakable

> [image]

Answer (score 11):

Both un- and -bar are [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)) affixes, so speakers can add them to (at least some) existing words to form new ones even if they are not yet in dictionaries. This isn't any different from how un- and -able work in English. One radio show here in Austria has a segment called "[die ungooglebare Frage](https://www.kronehit.at/podcast/die-ungooglebarefrage/)" = "the ungoogleable question".

The other answer is right that "unaufhaltsam" is a more common and natural-sounding word.

Answer (score 5):

"Unbremsbar" would be a valid German word, so to speak, but from my experience it's not even remotely commonly used. A more natural way to express the sentiment would be a phrase like "nicht zu bremsen" ("not breakable" or "impossible to break").

Comment: Not brakeable  = impossible to brake.

Answer (score 3):

It's a word you can use. The more common replacement for most of the shown cases might be "unaufhaltsam" or "unermüdlich" - though especially the first, 2nd and 2nd-last examples are rather examples of at least very liberal translations as IMHO the German does not correspond overly well to what the English sentence expresses.

Answer (score 0):

It exists, but it is not a very common word. Google Ngram shows the following:

[image]

You see that there are some peaks. Around 1990 it acieved a frequency of occurrence of ca. 0.00000400% (which shows that is was an "exotic" word).

The diagram also indicates that it occured for the first time in 1932 and was used until 1945. It seems plausible that the Nazis had some preference for it, perhaps they wanted to say that the Third Reich took an unstoppable rise.

I guess all peaks are related to certain events. Here are some speculations:

- Peak beginning in 1954 : Germany won the Football World Cup + Wirtschaftswunder
- Peak in the seventies : Germany won the European Football Championshipin 1972 and the Football World Cup in 1974
- Peak around 1990 : German reuinfication in 1989, Football World Cup in 1990
- Peak around 2000 : Introduction of the [Euro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro) between 1999 and 2002

Let us compare it with the word "unaufhaltsam":

[image]

This word is and was used[much frequently and much earlier. The first peak may be correlated to the [Thirty Years' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War).